# bombardier add header as json

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, bombardier

I trying to add json as value for http request header in bombardier, but when I deserialize it in ASP.NET application I get exception : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Input string 'key' is not a valid number. Path 'key', line 1,

the value of this key is a string

What is wrong?

this is my bombardier params:

```
-c 5 -n 1 -l   -H ""HeaderName": {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}" -m POST http://localhost:5000/v2/ -H "Cookie: CookieName1=value1 ; CookieName2=value2; CookieName3=value3"
```

Comment: What is the class you are deserializing it into? It sounds like one of the values should be a number, but you're presenting it as a string (wrapping it in quotes).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.